# Problem with strongSwan

Tags: linux, debian, scripting, vpn, strongswan

I have a VPN server with Ubuntu and IKEv2 protocol using strongSwan.

We create clients using the bash `user.sh` script, but we have a problem as shown below.

When the number of clients increases - to more than 1,000 users - they do not connect to the server while the server will create accounts by mentioned command correctly.

Meanwhile there is below the content of the `user.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#copyright all right reserved by hjyy
YOUR_VPN_USERNAME=''
YOUR_PASSWORD=''
YOUR_USER_ID=''
[ -n "$VPN_USERNAME" ] && VPN_USER="$YOUR_VPN_USERNAME"
[ -n "$PASSWORD" ] && VPN_PASSWORD="$YOUR_PASSWORD"
[ -n "$USER" ] && USER_ID="$YOUR_USER_ID"
if [ -z "$VPN_EMAIL" ] && [ -z "$VPN_USER" ] && [ -z "$VPN_PASSWORD" ];    then
  echo "VPN credentials not set by VPN_USER. Generating random  password..."
  echo
  VPN_USER="$(LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc 'a-z2-9' < /dev/urandom | head -c 5)"
  VPN_PASSWORD="$(LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc '2-9' < /dev/urandom | head -c 5)"
  USER_ID="$(LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc '1-9' < /dev/urandom | head -c 8)"

fi

if [ -z "$VPN_USER" ] || [ -z "$VPN_PASSWORD" ]; then
  exiterr "All VPN credentials must be specified. Edit the script and re-enter them."
fi
echo "Adding VPN_USER setup in progress... Please be patient."  
echo
cd /etc/ || exiterr "Cannot enter /etc/strongswan/."
sudo sh -c "echo ' : RSA ike.ovpadd.com.key
$VPN_USER  : EAP \"$VPN_PASSWORD\"' >>  /var/lib/strongswan/$VPN_USER.secrets.inc"
sudo sh -c "echo 'include /var/lib/strongswan/$VPN_USER.secrets.inc' >>      /etc/ipsec.secrets"
chmod -Rf 775 include /var/lib/strongswan/$VPN_USER.secrets.inc
echo "Copyright all right reserved by securedv.net"
echo "username is: $VPN_USER and password is :$VPN_PASSWORD"
echo "please run this code for delete user after <time> : bash d.sh     /var/lib/strongswan/$VPN_USER.secrets.inc <time> "
sudo service strongswan restart
exit 0)
```

Are there any mistakes in the script?

As I explained there are no problems creating accounts using the mentioned command, but when the amount increases, then none of them are able to connect to the server; I have to use the last backup to solve the issue, but in this case I lose newly created users.

Would you advise about the cause of the problem?

Comment: How many users have you got now?

Comment: about 3000 User

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to the behaviour you describe about strongSwan not connecting *new users* or not connecting users at all when `ipsec.secrets` grows too much, we can assuredly say the problem is not having errors in the scripts.

It seems you are hitting a file/buffer/memory limit. The real question is that your user base has outgrown your current setup, e.g. your setup maybe be the ideal for a smaller user base, however not indicated for that many users.

As a temporary work around, you might consider breaking down the user list into several VPN servers.

However, in the medium/long term, I would advise setting up a central authentication server, be it RADIUS, LDAP, MySQL or Active Directory instead of creating users in  `ipsec.secrets`, *and* setting up a new infra-structure for enabling StrongSwan to authenticate over it.

The documentation still classifies the SQL plugin as experimental. There also plugins for PAM, however I would not recommend them.

FreeRadius also talks with a backend LDAP configuration, and understands more protocols if properly configured (namely PAP, MSCHAPv2, EAP-PAP *and* EAP-MSCHAPv2). Using a RADIUS protocol also brings the added advantage of having the accounting data in a central point. With a proper setup (i.e. FreeRadius dumping accounting in MySQL, which is an optional configuration) you can very easily have listings of the VPN usage by the users.

As such, while more complicated I would recommend for a service of your size, to have strongSwan talking to FreeRADIUS, and [FreeRADIUS](http://freeradius.org) talking to an LDAP backend with your users and passwords.

As per the official documentation:

[Authentication with RADIUS](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/EAPRAdius) (with FreeRadius for instance)

> EAP-Radius The eap-radius plugin does not implement an EAP method
>   directly, but it redirects the EAP conversation with a client to a
>   RADIUS backend server. On the gateway, the EAP packets get extracted
>   from the IKE messages and encapsulated into the RADIUS protocol, and
>   vice versa. The gateway itself does not need special support for a
>   specific EAP method, as it handles the EAP conversation between the
>   client and the RADIUS backend more or less transparently.
>
> RADIUS servers The plugin should work with any RADIUS server, we
>   tested it successfully with FreeRADIUS and the NPS Server included
>   with Windows Server 2008 R2.
>
> For EAP methods providing an MSK, the RADIUS server must include the
>   key within the MPPE-Send/Receive Keys; Unfortunately, FreeRADIUS
>   before 2.1.10 did not include these attributes when used with
>   EAP-MSCHAPv2.

Alternative you can also use [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org), which is an open source firewall based on FreeBSD that has a web graphical interface; you will still have the problem of sorting out a scalable and maintainable backend.

I will also add as an example, that I am managing a couple of pfSense IPsec VPNs for several thousand users authenticating into FreeRadius+Active Directory. They are using the native VPN clients of Windows 7 to 10, MacOS, iOS, Linux, and Android.

Also in what touches integration with WHMCS: disclaimer - I am not familiar with [WHMCS](https://www.whmcs.com).  However it seems to me it only concerns billing in a VPN solution. I do suspect that after having a unified RADIUS configuration in place putting usage in MySQL, there is still some software development to do to integrate the usage/billing with WHMCS. If not that, it is far more complicated to do the heavy lifting of extracting from different platforms the logs of customer usage.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed explanation. 

We have several VM which different protocols. Such as Softether Multi-Protocol (L2TP, Open VPN and SSL VPN), ikeV2 and PPTP are installed on VMs.
But each of them have separated Authentication structure and due to this reason I want to integrate all of them by WHMCS, 
So kindly please let me know if WHMCS is suitable for this task of integration.
Regard, 
Hooman

Comment: I added to the answer.